# Multiplication in bc (bench calculator)

Tags: bc

```
$ echo 2*1024|bc
20480
$ echo 2.0*1024|bc
2048.0
$ echo 2*1024.0|bc
2048.0
```

What's going on here then?

Update:

dc manages fine

```
$ echo "2 1024 * p"|dc
2048
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the `bc` sum (`2*1024`) in single quotes (') does it make a difference?  It could well be that the shell is interpreting the `*` as a wildcard and expanding it in some way.

```
$ echo '2*1024' | bc
```

should give you better results.

Comment: Aha! Turns out I had a file called 20*1024 for some reason.